# Python TAPI COM object with events

Tags: python, tapi

I try use win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents for TAPI COM object

```
import win32com.client
class TapiEvents:
    pass

tapi = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("{21D6D48E-A88B-11D0-83DD-00AA003CCABD}",TapiEvents)
```

But it gives an error:
This COM object does not support events.

Answer (score 2):

A working example looks like (working with CiscoTSP)

```
import win32com.client
cls="TAPI.TAPI.1"
# need for gen_py
ti = win32com.client.Dispatch(cls)._oleobj_.GetTypeInfo()
tlb, index = ti.GetContainingTypeLib()
tla = tlb.GetLibAttr()
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule(tla[0], tla[1], tla[3], tla[4], bValidateFile=0)

class TapiEvents(win32com.client.getevents(cls)):
    def OnEvent(self, ev1,ev2): 
        print "OnEvent"

tapi=win32com.client.Dispatch(cls)
tapi.Initialize() # must run after Dispatch and before TapiEvents
events=TapiEvents(tapi)
tapi.EventFilter = 0x1FFFF

for addr in tapi.Addresses: 
    try:
        tapi.RegisterCallNotifications(addr,True,True,8,0)
    except:
        pass

import Tix
r=Tix.Tk()
r.mainloop()
```

For making call use

```
import win32com.client,time
tapi = win32com.client.Dispatch("TAPI.TAPI.1")
tapi.Initialize()
for item in tapi.Addresses: print item.AddressName
objCrtAddress = [item for item in tapi.Addresses if 'SEP' in item.AddressName][0]
sNumber='323'
gobjCall = objCrtAddress.CreateCall(sNumber, 1, 0x8)
gobjCall.Connect (False)
```

Comment: thanks so much for the example, this is the best I could find so far for using the TAPI in Python, do you have more hints for me how I can find out more like: How did you know that you have to set the tapi.EventFilter = 0x1FFFF to this value, which events do you filter with that?

Comment: I am very pleased that my example is useful. Thank You, @select.
I had great difficulty finding the information.
Example in python I have not found at all.
Here are some links with examples in C ++, C # and VB, which helped me to understand (more VB).
[tapi.info](http://www.tapi.info/default.aspx/TAPI/PSDKSamples.html) (example **calldemo.htm** helped me a lot)
`tapi.EventFilter = 0x1FFFF` also in this example.
[msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TAPI-3-in-C-Get-Lines-and-dd143eaf) If you have any questions, tell me and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

While [Arty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426760/4829915) led the way for me, it's unfortunately at least by now both **broken** (probably due to [using Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)) and **partial** (e.g. displaying a literal "OnEvent" instead of event details, opening a whole menu (and thus getting broken on portable menu-less Python) without actually using it just for the sake of simulating an unofficial while loop, etc.).

I've therefore created my own version that:

1. Works in Python v3.
2. Displays every possible incoming call details (based on [Tapi CALLINFO_STRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tapi3if/ne-tapi3if-callinfo_string)), but only if the data exists.
3. Replaces `TAPI.TAPI.1` with `TAPI.TAPI` to reduce changes to being obsolete.
4. Actually uses a menu, but only if the the user decides so (`print_console = True/False`).
5. Dials numbers by accepting a number as a command line parameter.
6. Allowing to dial from all modems and alternatively displaying why all modems didn't match the requested one.

Don't forget to install [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) first.

**Show incoming calls**

(`python callerid.py`)

```
import pythoncom, time
import win32com.client
cls="TAPI.TAPI"
# need for gen_py
ti = win32com.client.Dispatch(cls)._oleobj_.GetTypeInfo()
tlb, index = ti.GetContainingTypeLib()
tla = tlb.GetLibAttr()
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule(tla[0], tla[1], tla[3], tla[4], bValidateFile=0)

print_console = False

class TapiEvents(win32com.client.getevents(cls)):
    def OnEvent(self, ev1,ev2): 
        constants = win32com.client.constants
        if ev1 == constants.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION:
            call = win32com.client.Dispatch(ev2).Call
            try:
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDIDNAME)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDIDNUMBER)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CONNECTEDIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNAME)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNAME)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNUMBER)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNAME)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNUMBER)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDPARTYFRIENDLYNAME", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDPARTYFRIENDLYNAME)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_COMMENT", call, constants.CIS_COMMENT)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_DISPLAYABLEADDRESS", call, constants.CIS_DISPLAYABLEADDRESS)
               print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLINGPARTYID", call, constants.CIS_CALLINGPARTYID)
            except:
               pass

def print_check_error(str, obj, code):
   try:
    output = obj.CallInfoString(code)
    if bool(output):
       if print_console:
          print(f"{str}: {output}")
       else:
          update_text(f"{str}:\n{output}")
   except:
     pass

def update_text(str):
    label.config(text=str)

tapi=win32com.client.Dispatch(cls)
tapi.Initialize() # must run after Dispatch and before TapiEvents
events=TapiEvents(tapi)
tapi.EventFilter = 0x1FFFF

for addr in tapi.Addresses: 
    try:
        tapi.RegisterCallNotifications(addr,True,True,8,0)
    except:
        pass

if not print_console:
  try:
     import tkinter as tk
     r = tk.Tk()
     r.geometry(f"500x300+{int((r.winfo_screenwidth() / 2.5) - (r.winfo_reqwidth() / 2))}+{int((r.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (r.winfo_reqheight() / 2))}")
     r.title("Incoming calls")
     label = tk.Label(r, text="Waiting for calls")
     label.pack()
     r.mainloop()
  except:
     print_console = True
     pass

if print_console:
  try:
     while True:
        pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
        time.sleep(0.01)  # Don't use up all our CPU checking constantly
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
     pass
```

**Dial numbers**

(`python call.py [enter number]`)

```
import sys
import win32com.client,time
tapi = win32com.client.Dispatch("TAPI.TAPI")
tapi.Initialize()
# for item in tapi.Addresses: print(item.AddressName)
modemAll = False
modem = "USB"

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    sNumber = sys.argv[1]
else:
    exit("Send a phone number to the program")

found = False
modemList = []
for item in tapi.Addresses:
   if modemAll or modem in item.AddressName:
     found = True
     gobjCall = item.CreateCall(sNumber, 1, 0x8)
     gobjCall.Connect (False)
     if not modemAll:
        break
   else:
     modemList.append(item.AddressName)
if not found:
   modemList = str(modemList).strip('[]').replace(',', '\n')
   print(f"No modem matched {modem} in\n{modemList}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The callerid.py sample raises this error on Python 2.7, 3.8 and 3.11 on Windows 10. All efforts to get RegisterCallNotifications done are in vain.

```
> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft TAPI 3.0 Type Library.ITAddress2 instance
> at 0x14352208> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Dropbox/py-prog/remote_atis/tapi/callerid.py", line 55, in
> <module>
>     tapi.RegisterCallNotifications(addr, True, True, 8, 0)   File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\21D6D480-A88B-11D0-83DD-00AA003CCABDx0x1x0.py",
> line 3297, in RegisterCallNotifications
>     return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(65539, LCID, 1, (3, 0), ((9, 1), (11, 1), (11, 1), (3, 1), (3, 1)),pAddress pywintypes.com_error:
> (-2147352567, 'Exception', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221500),
> None)
```